# How to draw a table 2*1+3*1 in `tabular`:

Tags: tabularx

How to draw such table in `tabular`:
[image]

even in the `Word`, I can only generate a `6*2 table` then merge each column respectively.

I prefer use the two table method since it is easy to understand and much  compatible with other code. But I happened to a new problem in my real situation
[image]

There is a additional row at the top of each table, their height should be equal. Then how to do this using two table method and need I accept the answer here then open o new question?

Comment: Why not creating two tables and putting them side by side?

Comment: Other than starting and ending at the same (vertical) place, do the two columns share  any other constraints, such as all cells in a given column are of fixed height?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you need this for; because this seems like a really bad idea for a table (I recommend you read the “booktabs” vignette, which explains how tables should be used properly). On the other hand, it might be an acceptable chart (rather than a table). This will necessitate a quite different technical solution in LaTeX though (e.g. using TikZ).

Comment: What's 'the two table method'? What code do you have? Why have you edited your question in a way which renders existing answers inevitably incomplete? Please ask a new question and include a minimal working example, linking this question if appropriate.

Comment: @cfr ok, I will open a new question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use nested tabulars:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|@{} l @{}|@{} c @{}|}\hline
  \begin{tabular}{ l }
    some text in the left\\\cline{1-1}
    some more text in the left column\\
  \end{tabular}
&  
  \begin{tabular}{ l }
    some text in the left\\\hline
    some text in the left\\\hline
    some more text in the left column
\end{tabular}\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or with

```
\begin{tabular}{|@{} c @{}|@{} c @{}|}\hline
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.8}%    <====
    \begin{tabular}{ l }
```

[image]

Comment: Why is the vertical alignment in the 2-row left column inconsistent, and is there a way to center the text vertically? I've tried a couple of things but no success so far... A brute force approach `\raisebox{4pt}{...}` works, but is, well, brute force.

Comment: To clarify: `\raisebox{4pt}{...}` is for the top row, and `\raisebox{-3pt}{...}` for the bottom row.

Comment: What about "some text in the right" somewhere? ;-)

Comment: @sgmoye: See edited answer

Comment: I prefer use two tables, but what's the meaning of `|@{} l @{}|@{} c @{}|` here? And is it allowed to use two tables with column more than 1, that's why I ask the first question.

Comment: I have accepted your answer and open a new question.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative to `tabular`...stacked `\framebox`es.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackgap{S}{\fboxrule}
\begin{document}
\Shortstack{%
\framebox(100,30){}
\framebox(100,30){}}%
\Shortstack{%
\framebox(100,20){}
\framebox(100,20){}
\framebox(100,20){}}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

With text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackgap{S}{\fboxrule}
\begin{document}
\Shortstack{%
\framebox(100,30){left top}
\framebox(100,30){left bottom}}%
\Shortstack{%
\framebox(100,20){right top}
\framebox(100,20){right center}
\framebox(100,20){right bottom}}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Variable box height.  As long as the `\framebox` heights add to the same number in each column, the top and bottom will be aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackgap{S}{\fboxrule}
\begin{document}
\Shortstack{%
\framebox(100,30){left top}
\framebox(100,30){left bottom}}%
\Shortstack{%
\framebox(100,13){right top}
\framebox(100,30){\stackanchor[4pt]{right}{center}}
\framebox(100,17){right bottom}}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can actually do it the same way as in `Word`, by merging cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{left 1} & \multirow{2}{*}{right 1} \\
                        &                          \\ \cline{2-2} 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{right 2} \\ \cline{1-1}
\multirow{3}{*}{left 2} &                          \\ \cline{2-2} 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{right 3} \\
                        &                          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX output for code above]

Comment: That's clever--I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: best usage of least common multiple :)

Comment: I thought about this method before, but here is a problem that, if the case is 5row + 6row, then I need to creare 30row totally.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that allows automatic line-breaking in all cells. The solution uses a "outer" `tabularx` environment (with a total width of your choice; below, the total width is set to `\textwidth`) with two columns, and two "inner" side-by-side `tabular` environments with one column each. There can be any number of logical "rows" in each of the two inner `tabular` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for "\RaggedRight" macro

%% filler text
\newcommand\blurbA{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.}
\newcommand\blurbB{Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus.}
\newcommand\blurbC{Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempus convallis augue. Etiam facilisis. Nunc elementum fermentum wisi. Aenean placerat.}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look"
\newcolumntype{P}[1]%
  {>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-2\tabcolsep\relax}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|@{}X@{}|@{}X@{}|}
\hline
%% left-hand column
\begin{tabular}[t]{P{\hsize}}
\blurbA\\ \hline
\blurbC % optional: \\ \hline
\end{tabular} &
%% right-hand column
\begin{tabular}[t]{P{\hsize}}
\blurbB\\ \hline
\blurbA\\ \hline
\blurbB
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would not for an instant claim that this is the most elegant solution to this problem. Further, using Ti*k*Z to accomplish this seems a bit like using a sledge hammer to crack a peanut. It is, however, visually neat and clean, and is easily altered to suit. Suggestions for improvement, as usual, are welcome...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

%% Any number of rows might be accomodated, you just have to set 'minimum height' accordingly
\tikzset{
    tworow/.style={%
        draw,
        minimum height=3\baselineskip,
        text width=0.5\textwidth-8pt, % 8pt is 2*inner sep + 2*line width (about)
        align=left
        },
    threerow/.style={
        draw,
        minimum height=2\baselineskip,
        text width=0.5\textwidth-8pt,
        align=left
    }
}

\newcommand{\twothreetable}[5]{
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0.0pt,line width=1pt]% Alter 'line width' to suit
    \node (B)[tworow,anchor=south west] {#1};
    \node (C)[tworow,anchor=north west] {#2};
    %
    \node (D)[threerow,anchor=north west] at (B.north east) {#3};
    \node (E)[threerow,anchor=north west] at (D.south west) {#4};
    \node[threerow,anchor=north west] at (E.south west) {#5};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\twothreetable{Text 1 and a bit to indicate what happens with a lot of text}
{Text 2}
{Text 3}
{Text 4}
{Text 5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, I think using TiKZ her is way more appropriate than the other solutions: this is a *chart*, not a *table* (or rather, it would be an acceptable chart rather than a poor table).

Answer (score 1):

With `tcbposter` (from `tcolorbox`) you can construct all kind of complex box distributions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
    poster={columns=2,rows=3, height=3cm,spacing=-.5mm},
    boxes={colframe=black, colback=white, sharp corners, notitle, valign=center}
    ]
    \posterbox{name=11,column=1,row=1,rowspan=1.5}{First box}
    \posterbox{column=1,below=11,rowspan=1.5}{Second box}
    \posterbox{column=2,row=1}{Second column, first row}
    \posterbox{column=2,row=2}{Second column, second row}
    \posterbox{column=2,row=3}{Second column, third row}
\end{tcbposter} 

\begin{tcbposter}[
    poster={columns=2,rows=4, height=5cm, width=.8\textwidth,spacing=-.5mm},
    boxes={colframe=black, colback=white, sharp corners, notitle, valign=center, halign=center}
    ]

\posterbox[colback=green!20, fontupper=\large]
{row=1,column=1,span=2}{Nice title} 

\posterbox[colback=red!70!blue!30]{name=A,column=1,row=2,rowspan=1.2}{A}

\posterbox[colback=red!30!blue!70,valign=bottom, halign=right]{column=1,between=A and bottom}{B}

\posterbox[colback=red!30]{name=C,column=2,row=2,rowspan=0.6}{C}

\posterbox[colback=red!30!cyan!80]{name=E,column=2, above=bottom, rowspan=1.2}{E}

\posterbox[colback=red!80!cyan!30,halign=left]{column=2,between=C and E}{D}
\end{tcbposter} 
\end{document}
```

[image]